# Change multiple cell properties VBA

Tags: excel, vba

If I have a line

```
Range("S434").Value = "whatever"
```

can I affix

.Font.Color = vbRed

at the end somehow, or will I need a new line? Thanks

Comment: You will need a separate line.

Comment: VBA typically doesn't support chaining of commands

Answer (score 3):

Usually:

```
Sub uncle()
    With Range("s434")
        .Value = "whatever"
        .Font.Color = vbRed
    End With
End Sub
```

but:

```
Sub uncle()
    With Range("s434")
        .Value = "whatever": .Font.Color = vbRed
    End With
End Sub
```

Also works *(using a colon allows several logical lines of code to be entered on one physical line)*

This reference is for VB.NET, but it mostly applies to VBA as well:

[splitting or combining lines of code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/program-structure/how-to-break-and-combine-statements-in-code)

Answer (score 2):

Or you can build a ”helper” sub to do all the work and you use one code line only in your “main” code to call it:

```
Sub DoAll(rng As Range, myValue As Variant, myColor As Long)
    With rng
        .Value = myValue
        .Font.Color = myColor
    End With
End Sub
```

So that your “main” code will be

```
‘.... your code
DoAll Range("s434"), "whatever", vbRed
‘... rest of your code
```